# Why does Api platform(2.7) saved invalid data via PUT method?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

I need a little help..
I have started using symfony(v6.2) with api platform(v2.7) and met a particular problem.

1. First, I created a simple entity with @Assert to try this.
   This is my simple \App\Entity\Test code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\TestRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TestRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class Test
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 10, max: 255)]
    private ?string $text = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setText(string $text): self
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

2. I tried to send a simple POST method and it worked great. I got an error because @Assert is working, It doesn't create a new record in the database, so great:

Request body: `{"text": "a"}`

Response body:

```
  "@context": "/api/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
  "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "text: This value is too short. It should have 10 characters or more.",
  "violations": [
    {
      "propertyPath": "text",
      "message": "This value is too short. It should have 10 characters or more.",
      "code": "9ff3fdc4-b214-49db-8718-39c315e33d45"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Well, I wanted to try the PUT method... So I used the same thing as for POST.

- I sent the same data as for the POST
- I got the same error as for the POST

But, this data (`{"text": "a"}`) had been saved(updated)! I just don't get it, how does it possible? I got an exception and ApiPlatform was able to save the wrong data.
Why is @Assert working with the POST method? What is the difference between the two?
I mean, it should work in either case.

I looked through this topic: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation/
and tried all ways and it is not working.
What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, your example looks correct. Try to debug in `ApiPlatform\Symfony\EventListener\ValidateListener::onKernelView()`. Looking to https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/ it should be executed before `WriteListener` and stop on validation error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the problem is the firewall config. I set **stateless:false** in security.yaml and after changed to true, the API platform - PUT method is working correctly. I don't understand why it depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of the problem. If you use Symfony security.yaml with `stateless: false` option, the end of each (**authenticated**) session will be saved. (Even though you get a @Assert|Violation error). I think this behaviour is the default in the Symfony framework. It strives to avoid data loss (only if you are logged in).

My solution is to use transaction middleware.
For example:

```
class TransactionMiddleware
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private bool $transactionStarted = false;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }


    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (
            str_starts_with($request->getPathInfo(), '/api') &&
            in_array($request->getMethod(), ['PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
        ) {
            $this->entityManager->beginTransaction();
            $this->transactionStarted = true;
        }
    }


    public function onKernelTerminate(TerminateEvent $event): void
    {
        if ($this->transactionStarted) {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
                $this->entityManager->commit();
            } else {
                $this->entityManager->rollback();
            }

            $this->transactionStarted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```
#services.yaml

    App\EventListener\TransactionMiddleware:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: onKernelTerminate }
```

I have already tested and it works.